# Cropping image before of after upload to server

Tags: php

So I've got this PHP script to scale and crop into a square from the center;

```
<?PHP
//resize and crop image by center
function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 80){
    $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
    $width = $imgsize[0];
    $height = $imgsize[1];
    $mime = $imgsize['mime'];

    switch($mime){
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
            $image = "imagegif";
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
            $image = "imagepng";
            $quality = 7;
            break;

        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
            $image = "imagejpeg";
            $quality = 80;
            break;

        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
    $src_img = $image_create($source_file);

    $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
    $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
    //if the new width is greater than the actual width of the image, then the height is too large and the rest cut off, or vice versa
    if($width_new > $width){
        //cut point by height
        $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
        //copy image
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
    }else{
        //cut point by width
        $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, $max_height, $width_new, $height);
    }

    $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);

    if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
    if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
}
//usage example
resize_crop_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");p_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");
?>
```

You can simply call the following function:

```
resize_crop_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");p_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");
```

Added to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqm40gud/) is my HTML5/JQuery preview file before uploading to the server.

**1).** Do I need to upload the image to the server before running this script?

**2).** If needing to prior upload, how can I use my form to upload into a temp location, do the job and move to a specific dir and delete the temp dir?

Comment: Do you mean follow this tutorial: http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1304

Comment: 1) Yes, a copy of the image will need to be on server before you can edit/crop it. 2) Uploaded files are automatically stored in the temp directory (they are usually copied out to use the image, but don't have to be). They can be read as an image from the temp directory by your code and PHP will also automatically clean up the file at the end of the script.

Comment: ^ @JonathanKuhn, first question is now clear and it seems most of my second question is done for me!

Comment: When a file gets uploaded, in the `$_FILES` array there is a key with the tmp name. You can just pass that into your function as the source file and it should work with imagecopyresampled with no issue. The temp name will be something like `$_FILES['nameFromFileFieldOnForm']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: Just [check this script](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof/blob/master/src/bulletproof.php#L527-L589) replace ` $mimeType` with the images mimes type and and `$image` to an array with width and height as `$image['width'] = 40`, `$image['height'] = 20` .. it is easy, try it.

Comment: In that script I cannot see where I tell the script the image is? Does this script scale and from an image from, for example; 225x523px to 120x120px without any stretching?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn despite my lack of knowledge and full understanding, this pretty much sounds like the answer. Why don't you say this as an answer to get this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, a copy of the image will need to be on server before you can edit/crop it. 2) Uploaded files are automatically stored in the temp directory (they are usually copied out to use the image, but don't have to be). They can be read as an image from the temp directory by your code and PHP will also automatically clean up the file at the end of the script.

When a file gets uploaded, in the `$_FILES` array there is a key with the tmp name. You can just pass that into your function as the source file and it should work with `imagecopyresampled` with no issue. The temp name will be something like `$_FILES['nameFromFileFieldOnForm']['tmp_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

if your source file or destination file is

```
$source_file = www.example.com/storage/packages/image.jpg
```

change it to

```
$source_file = ./storage/packages/image.jpg
```

It works for me in laravel 5